# I am confused as to how this PHP code is not only valid but produces no syntax errors?

Tags: php, syntax

I did a find-replace and made a mistake which led to the following code being on it's own line.

```
16;
```

This caused a lot of issues as it did not produce any errors anywhere and I am very surprised. How is this possibly valid PHP code?

Comment: What's *invalid* about it? It simply doesn't *do* anything.

Comment: @deceze I was just shocked that it didn't cause a 500 error, or PHP didn't flag a warning. Even VS Code was fine with this. It was silently causing functionality in my code to not work and I had no idea.

Comment: Just like `$a;`. Nothing wrong with it. Not very useful tough

Comment: @figgyfarts Nothing in this line of code should cause errors nor silent changes in functionality. It doesn't *do* anything.

Comment: You can use a static analyzer like [PHPStan](https://phpstan.org/) to find useless code like this. In this case, it would warn you with a message like `Expression "16" on a separate line does not do anything.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`16` is a valid literal. In itself it is a valid expression. `16;` is a statement made up of the expression `16` which consists of the single value `16`. There's nothing invalid. It simply doesn't *do* anything.